# Is there a way to disable Safari CSP (Content Security Policy) check?

Tags: safari, content-security-policy, userscripts, safari-extension

Seems like Safari has a very strong restriction on CSP. For example, on GitHub, most of the userscripts and extension doesn't work because of that.

I got a such error from the console.

> [Error] Refused to execute a script because its hash, its nonce, or 'unsafe-inline' does not appear in the script-src directive of the Content Security Policy. (pulls, line 0)

How can I stop CSP check in Safari?

Comment: Do you have a plug-in or something that might be adding CSP restrictions to your browser? It doesn’t make sense that Safari is treating the same page more strictly than other browsers

Comment: Related: [Safari: Script unable to bypass CSP](https://github.com/Tampermonkey/tampermonkey/issues/296) issue on GitHub.